# Is there such a thing as a public, curated list of people who WANT to be e-mailed?

Tags: database, csv, email

I've always wanted to be able to send e-mails to a lot of people, for example to announce something.

However, there are ultra-strict rules for this and basically, you destroy your "reputation" if you "buy a list" of contact information and send them e-mails, as many will (apparently) "mark as spam" or not even open it, somehow resulting in penalties for your domain/IP address.

So, is there a database for free listing all the ones who *do* want to get e-mails? For example, news people who gladly will wade through a lot of junk to find a hot "scoop" before anyone else, or investors with a similar mindset, or just people in general who, in some manner, have announced that they are perfectly fine with receiving unsolicited e-mails and therefore will be safe to "spam" without risking any anger from them?

I've many times attempted to compile my own such lists by visiting the websites of numerous newspapers, but it quickly exhausted me and it just doesn't seem reasonable.

Of course, these people would still be using spam filters and manual blocks, so they would not get overwhelmed, just like I'm not overwhelmed due to my numerous blocks of junk senders. The few spam e-mails that do fall through are more than manageable.